# ggplot "could not find function"

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

*New to ggplot*

I am trying to plot a the dataframe result which looks like this :

```
 County Mean_Porosity_Percent SD_Porosity_Percent
1    Custer              52.40714            3.807763
2  Franklin              49.63394            3.642400
3     Keith              48.46000            5.461044
4      Knox                   NaN                  NA
5   Lincoln              53.38125           10.414331
6    Nemaha              52.97400            2.915541
7      Otoe              56.45143            1.949730
8    Seward              53.55875            2.641381
9   Sherman              55.66250            6.577776
10  Stanton              57.54750                  NA
```

ggplot code:

```
ggplot(result, aes(x=County,y=Mean_Porosity_Percent), geom = "bar")
```

Error: could not find function "Mean_Porosity_Percent"

Comment: Not sure why you are seeing that error, but `geom` should not be inside `ggplot`. Try this: `ggplot(result, aes(x = County, y = Mean_Porosity_Percent)) + geom_col()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to explain that error (since the spelling of the column name looks correct), but I think you might want to use `geom_col` rather than `geom_bar`, since the latter function expects a count. Try instead:

```
ggplot(result, aes(x=County,y=Mean_Porosity_Percent) )+geom_col()
```

[image]

You should check the results of `str(result)`. Mine looks like this:

```
str(result)
#-------------
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ County               : Factor w/ 10 levels "Custer","Franklin",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ Mean_Porosity_Percent: num  52.4 49.6 48.5 NaN 53.4 ...
 $ SD_Porosity_Percent  : num  3.81 3.64 5.46 NA 10.41 ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The str(result) looks the same for me. I am unable to get the SD along with the mean for the plots for the same dataset.                                                                          Could you please suggest how to modify the plot code so that I can get the mean and SD? Also, geom_col() worked. Thanks again.

Comment: It would be rather easy to get a side by side plot of all means together and all sd's together by converting to long format dataframe. I'm not sure how easy it would be to get each mean next to each sd,